# File Zilla Server send report daily to email

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've installed FileZilla Server in my computer.
We created daily folder in FTP and wanted to send report daily (file's time created) to email on specific time.
Can FileZilla Server do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Can FileZilla Server do that?

As far as I am aware, no. You'll need separate software (program(s) and/or script(s)) to monitor the FTP folder for changes and to send an email with those changes.

If you want an automatically exported list of general folder changes, you might want to have a look at NirSoft's [FolderChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html). However, assuming you want just files and their creation dates (e.g. no folder data, etc.), you will likely need to parse the (by default CSV) output file produced by FolderChangesView in a separate script.

For emailing, you can likely use Windows Task Scheduler to run a script at a certain time which will "mail" the relevant information wherever you wish. For tools to use in the scheduled script, while [curl](https://curl.se/) is more of a general command-line utility for web-based interactions, one of its abilities is to send email. You can also use a purpose-built command-line mailing tool such as [blat](https://www.blat.net/). You can [download curl for Windows](https://curl.se/windows/) from the official curl website and [download blat from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/files/).

---

**Notes**

- You can set the export options for logged changes under *Options → Choose Base Folder* (also available through <kbd>F9</kbd>).
- If you want changes automatically exported (rather than doing this manually), you need ensure that the option to `Automatically export all folder changes to a file every...` is marked (checked) and an appropriate time is given. In the example below, folder changes will be export to `Changes.html` every 30 seconds:

*ex. FolderChangesView - Automatic Export Settings*

[image: FolderChangesView - Automatic Export Settings - Screenshot]

- You can reduce the export interval to as little as 1 second to obtain near-instantaneous updates:

*ex. Automatic Export Settings (Time Reduced)*

[image: FolderChangesView - Automatic Export Settings - Reduced - Screenshot]

**Caveats**

- Be aware that you cannot set the automatic export time to 0 seconds, or the option will (apparently) be ignored.
- After you update the export time interval, you may need to restart FolderChangesView to have the automatic export settings take effect.
- FolderChangesView needs to be running in order to have reports produced:

*ex. Stopped (No Automatic Report Produced)*

[image: FolderChangesView - Stopped]

*ex. Running (Automatic Report Produced [With Caveats, Above])*

[image: FolderChangesView - Running]

Comment: you will likely need to parse the (by default CSV) output file produced by FolderChangesView in a separate script. For this, I can't find the output section. Can you clarify?

Comment: This file:///C:/Users/David/Downloads/folderchangesview/report.html is not updated. When I want to see the latest report, it need manually to export.

Comment: *"When I want to see the latest report, it need manually to export."* - I have updated my answer. But in short, make certain `Automatically export all folder changes to a file every... X seconds` is marked (checked) and that the number of seconds is low enough to your liking. You can set the interval as low as 1 second to get near-instant report updates. Note that you (apparently) cannot set the time interval to 0 or the export option will be ignored.

Comment: Also, after you update the export time in seconds, you may need to restart FolderChangesView to ensure those changes take effect. That is, you may need to restart FolderChangesView to have the first report produced.

Comment: Lastly, ensure that FolderChangesView is running (actively monitoring a folder). The green "play" button (triangle) should be grayed out. Automatic reports won't be produced if it is stopped (not actively monitoring a folder i.e. the "red" stop button [square] is grayed out).